# Hyperlinks in select box not working

Tags: wordpress, select, hyperlink

been learning web design and I can not figure out why my hyperlinks do not work within the select box. I created the select box in Wordpress for navigation purposes, have declared the class name and put the HTML in raw.

Below is the JS, CSS, and HTML:

**JS**

```
var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
        and the selected item:*/
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
      and open/close the current select box:*/
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

**CSS**

```
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
}
.custom-select select {
  display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}
.select-selected {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/
.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
}
/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/
.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}
/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/
.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/*style items (options):*/
.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/
.select-hide {
  display: none;
}
.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="custom-select" onchange="location = this.value;">
 <option value="page1.html">Click here to go to page 1</option>
  <option value="page2.html">Click here to go to page 2</option>
</select>
```

Any help on fixing this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use F12 tools in your Browser in order to debug your code and also look for error / warnings. Add your findings to your question.

Comment: your code is working fine as a pure html, please check di you get any console errors in your browser

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I checked and there are no related errors in the console. When selecting a link from the select box, nothing happens.

Comment: If I delete the JS, it works fine, albeit without the extra styling/functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 'select' element would be hidden and the converted 'divs' only visible, the `onChange` event will not trigger (you are clicking the 'divs', not the 'select' element). Add `location = (s.options[i].value);` before `break;` and check.

Comment: Thanks very much, this fixed it!

Comment: If there are too many options in the select box, and on some screen resolutions as well as mobile devices you do not get to see all the choices, what is the best way to mitigate this?

Comment: I think you can achieve this with nested `ul` & `li` and `select` box not needed (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp for example). You can Google for more solutions. You can split a long dropdown into multiple sub-dropdowns in low resolution or mobile devices.